# Display local images using variables react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have an document in my db as follows:

```
doc = {
    _id: "11234324",
    image: "myimage.png"
}
```

I want to display myimage.png which exists locally:

path = "/Users/xxx/go/src/github.com/xxx/goapp/files/myImage.png"

I tried:

```
<img src={path+doc.image}/>
```

It does not work. I even can't use a variable inside require() function.

Any solutions how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem images are not dis played by most of the modern browser due to security reason.

BUT you can use an input type='file', then load the data, then display an image. That's how some react-cropper works.

Answer (score 1):

Does this local image exist somewhere on your device filesystem or in your project filesystem? In first case you will have to use something like [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs). In the second case you need to specifically `require` every image that you want to use in your project. Passing variables dynamically is not going to work, as `require` requires things at build time, not at runtime

Answer (score 1):

you can not show file that is outside of the project using require ,either you have to put the file in the project or in a cloud storage.
if you put it in project you can use the code like

```
const doc = {
    _id: "11234324",
    image: "myimage.jpg"
};
const path = '../images/'
```

and

```
<img src={require(path+doc.image)}/>
```

Comment: I figured this out. Thank you

Comment: can you give correct answer mark if you think it helped you